# What is the correct verb to use in a prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement

Sorry if my subject is a bit long-winded but I didn't know quite how to state it.  How about an example?

I'm making suggested edits to an online book that is also shortly coming out in a dead-trees version.  Here is the what I pointed out as being erroneous:

> parts of memory that *is* available

I have suggested that *are* is actually correct, not is.  They're insisting that's not the case, that "is" refers to "memory".  I'm no expert, but I believe that the necessary form of "to be" needs to correlate with "parts", not memory.  The way they've written it just sounds wrong.

EDIT: Sentence in full follows....

> Both the stack and the heap are parts of memory that is available to your code to use at runtime, but they are structured in different ways.

Comment: _Parts of the memory that are available_ seems correct, to me. Memory is available, true. But only certain parts are available, so the verb is plural.

Comment: You have to be careful to identify the subject correctly. _Parts of the memory that **is** available_ is also correct, but means something a little different (but not much). It depends on whether [_parts_] is modified by [_of the memory that **is** available_], meaning _parts of the available memory_, or whether [_parts of the memory_] is modified by [_that **are** available_], as you seem to parse it. In the first case, the relative clause modifies _memory_, a singular noun, so _is_ appears. In the second case, it modifies _parts of the memory_, a plural noun, so _are_ appears.

Comment: What is the sentence in full?

Comment: @BillJ  Am editing the question to include the full sentence; I was loathe to provide the full sentence at first because I didn't want to muddy the waters with "programmer speak" ;)  You will see that it even begins with "Both...." so again, a reference to something plural.

Comment: I agree with their edit. The context here qualifies that, used or not, the parts remain available to coding. It would most likely be better rewritten as, *"Both the stack and heap portions of memory are available for your code to use at runtime, but they are structured in different ways."*

Comment: The sentence does not need that is or that are at all. I will be glad to remove my answer but it really is basic English writing. And I'm surprised no one even said that. This is any editor's pet peeve.

Answer (score 4):

At first glance, you would appear to be correct. It makes sense that it should be ***parts*** *of memory that* ***are*** *available.*

The main subject of the sentence is the plural *parts*, so the verb also takes a plural form.

It's the same principle of construction as:

> The three **pieces** *of toast* **were** eaten.
>   The component **parts** *of the machine* **were** difficult to carry.
>   The **downpour** *of raindrops* that I **was** protected from by my umbrella didn't last long.

---

However, *they* could be correct if the sentence is parsed differently.

Rather than

> (**parts** of memory) that (**are** available)

it could be interpreted as

> (parts of) (**memory** that **is** available)

While I would say this is an unlikely interpretation, it's certainly not implausible. (Although, I would add a *the* in front of *memory*.)

In order to understand how the sentence should be phrased, you need to understand what's actually being described.

---

They might also have a semantic issue with memory being divided into components. You can have multiple memories, but a single memory could be considered indivisible. If that's the case (it depends on interpretation), then the phrase "pieces of memory" would need to be rephrased:

> The **memories** that **are** available.
>   The **memory** that **is** available.

This unstated assumption could then be colouring the verb they want to use.

But then their issue is with the description of the subject, not just with the subject-verb agreement.

Comment: I would remove the that is altogether.

Answer (score -1):

How to lighten your burden:

Your sentence is:

> **Both the stack and the heap are parts of memory that is available to your code to use at runtime, but they are structured in different
>   ways.***

B

> Both the stack and the heap are parts of memory available to your code
>   to be used at runtime  but they are structured in different ways**.

There is  no reason to use a relative pronoun here.

The relative pronoun can be left out when it is not the subject of the clause.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80491/discussion-on-answer-by-lambie-what-is-the-correct-verb-to-use-in-a-prepositiona).